# AttributeError when trying to change tkinter label color with bound command

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, label, attributeerror

I am trying to create a tkinter label that changes color when clicked to show that it has been visited. I keep getting an attribute error saying that Show_Label has no attribute 'fg'. Please help! Here is the code being used.

```
class Sheet_Label(Label):
    def __init__(self,master,text):

        Label.__init__(self,master,text=text,cursor="hand2",font="Times 16 underline",fg="blue")
        def button_click(event):
            if self.fg =="blue":
                self.fg = "purple"
            else:
                self.fg = "purple"
            location = os.getcwd()
            file = webbrowser.open_new(location + '\\' + "hello.txt")
        self.bind("<Button-1>",func=button_click)

def sheets_view():
    sheets_window = Toplevel(window)
    hello = modules.Sheet_Label(master=sheets_window,text="Hello")
    hello.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    sheets_window.title("Production Sheets")
    sheets_window.focus()
    x = (screen_width/2) - (500/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (500/2)
    sheets_window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (500,500,x,y))
    sheets_window.resizable(0,0)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\napaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "inventory.py", line 311, in sheets_view

    hello = modules.Sheet_Label(master=sheets_window,text="Hello")
  File "C:\Users\napaf\Documents\Programming\adco_project\modules.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.action = action
NameError: name 'action' is not defined
PS C:\Users\napaf\Documents\Programming\adco_project> python inventory.pyException in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\napaf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\napaf\Documents\Programming\adco_project\modules.py", line 27, in button_click
    if self.fg =="blue":
AttributeError: 'Sheet_Label' object has no attribute 'fg'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bg` instead of `fg`? What are you trying to achieve? Set the **b**ack**g**round color?

Comment: The attribute is fg because the foreground color of the text is the attribute I would like to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't initializing `self.fg` until `button_click` has been called, but at that point it's too late because you're trying to reference `self.fg` before setting it.

Also, `self.fg` is not the same as the `fg` attribute when you create the widget (eg: `Label(..., fg="blue")`. If you want to get the value of the widget attribute you should use `self.cget('fg')` or use the shortcut `self['fg']`. If you want to set it from within the class itself you should use `self.configure(fg="purple")`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly, for anyone wondering in the future, here are the changes I made:  `class Sheet_Label(Label):
    def __init__(self,master,text):


        Label.__init__(self,master,text=text,cursor="hand2",font="Times 16 underline",fg="blue")
        def button_click(event):
            if self['fg'] =="blue":
                self['fg'] = "purple"
            else:
                self['fg'] = "purple"
            location = os.getcwd()
            file = webbrowser.open_new(location + '\\' + "hello.txt")
        self.bind("<Button-1>",func=button_click)`

Comment: @BlorbieRandy: posting python code in a comment is pointless since all formatting is lost.